# Sample time serie by time interval with Hive QL and calculate jumps

Tags: hadoop, hive, time-series, hiveql

I have time series data in a table. Basically each row has a timestamp and a value.
The frequency of the data is absolutely random.

I'd like to sample it with a given frequency and for each frequency extract relevant information about it: min, max, last, change (relative previous), return (change / previous) and maybe more (count...)

So here's my input:

```
08:00:10, 1
08:01:20, 2
08:01:21, 3
08:01:24, 5
08:02:24, 2
```

And I'd like to get the following result for 1 minute sampling (ts, min, max, last, change, return):

```
ts        m  M  L  Chg   Return   
08:01:00, 1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL
08:02:00, 2, 5, 5, 4,    4
08:03:00, 2, 2, 2, -3,   -0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with something like this (comments inline):

```
SELECT
    min
  , mn
  , mx
  , l
  , l - LAG(l, 1) OVER (ORDER BY min) c
    -- This might not be the right calculation. Unsure how -0.25 was derived in question.
  , (l - LAG(l, 1) OVER (ORDER BY min)) / (LAG(l, 1) OVER (ORDER BY min)) r
FROM
(
  SELECT
      min
    , MIN(val) mn
    , MAX(val) mx
    -- We can take MAX here because all l's (last values) for the minute are the same.
    , MAX(l) l
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
        min
      , val
      -- The last value of the minute, ordered by the timestamp, using all rows.
      , LAST_VALUE(val) OVER (PARTITION BY min ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) l
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
          ts
        -- Drop the seconds and go back one minute by converting to seconds,
        -- subtracting 60, and then going back to a shorter string format.
        -- 2000-01-01 is a dummy date just to enable the conversion.
        , CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT("2000-01-01 ", ts), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + 60, "HH:mm"), ":00") min       
        , val
      FROM
        -- As from the question.
        21908430_input a
    ) val_by_min
  ) val_by_min_with_l
  GROUP BY min
) min_with_l_m_M
ORDER BY min
;
```

Result:

```
+----------+----+----+---+------+------+
| min      | mn | mx | l | c    | r    |
+----------+----+----+---+------+------+
| 08:01:00 | 1  | 1  | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 08:02:00 | 2  | 5  | 5 | 4    | 4    |
| 08:03:00 | 2  | 2  | 2 | -3   | -0.6 |
+----------+----+----+---+------+------+
```